# Retrieving data from Firebase (But stop listening for changes)

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm using Angular Firestore to communicate with a Firebase database. I have a collection of data in there that I want to retrieve, but I don't want to listen for changes, I just want to get the data and forget it. Here's my current attempt:

```
this.afs.collection(COLLECTION_PATH)
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((item) => {
        this.source.next(item);
    });
```

Which does do the job (sort of), but still executes again when the data changes. I've also tried using `.get()` instead of `.valueChanges()` and doing something similar but it returns odd types that I'm not completely sure how to work with so I didn't really want to go down that rabbit hole until I get a little advice.

My second problem with doing it this way is retrieval of this data from the rest of my app. This code is contained in a service, and I just want to populate an array of items to return. I have a function, `getItems()`, that simply returns all of the data from the code above. However, I have no way of telling when the above code completes, so in my components if I call `getItems()` in ngOnInit it's empty. If I hook `getItems()` onto a button and wait for a few seconds then I get data properly.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple.

```
let sub = this.afs.collection(COLLECTION_PATH)
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((item) => {
    sub.unsubscribe();
    this.source.next(item);
  });
```